# How to generate a very steep magnetic field gradient?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am a student that's very new to magnetism in general and I've been reading/learning for the past few weeks.

I'd like to build magnetic tweezers to use in materials with kPa order stiffness - so I would need very high fields and gradients.

However, from the little I understand, it looks like if I use ferromagnetic particles with the magnetic tweezers, the forces applied only depend on the field gradient? Torque doesn't matter to me - I just need to observe the displacement of the particles.

My main question and source of confusion is the following:

How do I generate very high/steep magnetic field gradients? 
Do I automatically need very high fields in order to have steep gradients?

I've done a lot of searching and all I could really find was a Helmholtz/Maxwell coil pair. I was wondering if there were any other ways to generate a very steep magnetic field gradient?

I am also open to using permanent magnets.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a cool project!

Historically, a strong gradient of the type you describe was required for the Stern-Gerlach experiment, for very similar reasons. They used a permanent magnet with one flat pole and one sharp pole, like this: [image: shaped magnet poles]

For more detail, see an example at the end of ch. 11 of my book [Simple Nature](http://www.lightandmatter.com/area1sn.html).

Comment: I would have guessed that the gradient would be stronger outside the tip of a pointed magnet if the second magnet were not there.  These days they are making very strong permanent magnets, but an electromagnet might be able to improve on that.